# Update User Foreign Key MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

Currently, I have a custom user.

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUser()
{
this.Applicants = new List<Applicant>();
}

public Nullable<DateTime> Expiration { get; set; }
public int Active { get; set; }

        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

The Company Class

```cs
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I want to update the User class so that it points to the company when the company is created; however, the update does not save. Here is the section of my controller where I am attempting to save the reference in the database. ApplicationUser should point to the ID of Company in the database.

```cs
// _db is for my Identity context
int id = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.GetUserId());
ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindById(id);
Company company = new Company
{
    Name = model.Name
};
_db.Companies.Add(company);
_db.SaveChanges();
user.Company = company;
UserManager.Update(user);
```

So what am I doing wrong or misunderstanding about the relationship between a user and it's relationships with objects rather than regular datatypes like string or int?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `virtual` to your navigational properties, e.g. `public virtual Company Company` and `public virtual ICollection...`. Without them being `virtual`, EF cannot track and/or persist them automatically.

Per the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057.aspx):

> **For change tracking proxies:**
>   Each property that is mapped to a property of an entity type in the data model must have non-sealed (NotOverridable in Visual Basic), public, and virtual (Overridable in Visual Basic) get and set accessors.